# A normal subgroup of the commutator subgroup (G,G) is normal in G

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I know from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275420/is-every-subgroup-of-a-normal-subgroup-normal) that any normal subgroup $K$ of a normal subgroup $H$ in a group $G$ is not necessarily normal in $G$. But I was wondering if this is true in the following case:

Let $G$ be a group. Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of the commutator subgroup $(G,G)$. Is $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$ ?

Thanks in advance for your enlightenment?

K. Y.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $G=A_4$, the alternating group of order $12$. Its derived subgroup is $V_4$, the unique Sylow $2$-subgroup of $A_4$. As $V_4$ is Abelian,
any of its $2$-element subgroups $H$ is normal in $V_4$, say $H=\left<(1\,2)(3\,4)\right>$. But $H$ is not normal in $A_4$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any condition we can add for the statement to be true?

Comment: If we take $H$ to be a characteristic subgroup of $[G,G]$, then $H$ will be normal in $G$.

Comment: Or $H$ a characteristic subgroup of any normal subgroup of $G$, again $H$ is normal in $G$.